# Is there any difference between `receive after` and `timer:sleep`?

Tags: erlang

The implementation of `timer:sleep` is:

```
-spec sleep(Time) -> 'ok' when
  Time :: timeout().
sleep(T) ->
    receive
    after T -> ok
    end.
```

So `timer:sleep` is equal to this code:

```
receive ->
    never_match -> %% note: this never to be matched
        ok 
    after 1000
        ok
end.
```

I want to know:

1. Is the process state for `timer:sleep` `sleeping` or `blocking`?
2. For Erlang VM process scheduling, is there any difference for this implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference between `timer:sleep/1` and a hardcoded `receive...after...end` statement (how could it be? The former is [*defined*](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/738c34d4bb8f1a3811acd00af8c6c12107f8315b/lib/stdlib/src/timer.erl#L150) as the latter).

Also, according to the documentation of [`process_info/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#process_info-1), a process' *status* can be:

```
Status :: exiting
        | garbage_collecting
        | waiting
        | running
        | runnable
        | suspended
```

In both cases (`timer` or `receive...`) the process is `waiting`.

```
4> spawn(fun() -> receive after 5000 -> ok end end).
<0.40.0>
5> process_info(v(4), status).                      
{status,waiting}
6> spawn(fun() -> timer:sleep(5000) end).           
<0.43.0>
7> process_info(v(6), status).           
{status,waiting}
```

Comment: for ` timer:sleep`, the erlang vm will make this process to be `hibernate`?

Comment: As you can see from the [code](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/738c34d4bb8f1a3811acd00af8c6c12107f8315b/lib/stdlib/src/timer.erl#L150) no, since there is no call to [`erlang:hibernate/3`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#hibernate-3).